# How to make a method to move a character in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

here's the deal, I have to make a game that resembles PacMan, with a map, points, ghosts, etc.
The whole thing works as an array[8][8], it reads the positions of walls and the initial position of ghosts from a .txt file, PacMan starts at a fixed location and Fruits are random. Any blank space at the beginning of the game gets filled with a simple point pellet.
I've got the map done, it shows it and everything, but I can't seem to come up with a method that allows the player to control PacMan with the keyboard... This is what I've tried so far...
In the Player class

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String mov = read.readLine();
if (mov.equals("w"))
{
  PacMan.MoveU();
}
```

It then repeats that for the other movement keys.

The individual Move methods in PacMan class look like this

```
public static void MoverR()
{
  for (int i=0;i<Tablero.length;i++)
  {
    for (int j=0;j<Tablero.length;j++)
    {
      if (Tablero[i][j] instanceof PacMan)
        Tablero[i][j]=null;
        Tablero[i][j+1]=new PacMan();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This obviously isn't working, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me with a more efficient way to do this? I really don't mind starting these two classes from scratch...
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you deleting your current `Pacman` and making a new one? I would keep `Pacman` separate from the table and just have `.x` and `.y` coordinates.

Comment: @Blender I guess I didn't know another way to go at it, I've just started to learn Java a couple of weeks ago, coming from C.

Comment: @JimRhodes It always gives me an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception, and another method I tried just did nothing at all...

Comment: Can you step through code with debugger and see what index is bad? How is Tablero declared?

Comment: @iVikD if you're just beginning, then you should probably try to stick to [java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: @iVikD I think the ArrayOutOfBounds Exception is caused by Tablero[i][j+1]=new PacMan(); when j == 7, because you try to access to an invalid position (Tablero[i][8]).

Comment: Tablero is declared in a parent class Element as
     `static Elemento[][] Tablero = new Elemento[8][8];`
I see, I get why it's out of bounds now, I need a new way to move PacMan then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It always gives me an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception*

The ArrayOutOfBounds Exception is caused by `Tablero[i][j+1]=new PacMan();` when `j == 7`, because you try to access to an invalid position (`Tablero[i][8]`).

> *anyone can help me with a more efficient way to do this?*

You don't need to check the whole array to find out the position of Pacman, you could store the position as a private variable of Pacman, but in that case you shouldn't create a new instance of Pacman every time you need to move it, like you are doing with your current implementation.

Comment: Ok, i've done this and seems to be behaving, but how do I make the Element class read PacMan at the location in the array?

Comment: @iVikD what is the Element class used for?

Comment: So far it has two methods, the Read() method uses Scanner to read a .txt file that contains the initial positions of walls and ghosts and sets them in the array `Tablero[3][3] = new Ghost();` like that. After reading the initial positions it sets the remaining empty spaces to simple point pellets. The other is a show method that uses a couple of fors to run through the whole array and showing '#' for wall, '@' for PacMan, `$` for ghosts, and so on.

Comment: @iVikD with this new approach, you should have only one instance of PacMan. If you need to update/retrieve its position, just set/get the position values of that instance. You don't really need to store PacMan in the Tablero array.

Comment: I see. If I don't need to store it there, how do I make the Show() method know where to show it?

Comment: @iVikD I imagine you have done something like this: `PacMan p = new PacMan();`. That way you create a instance of `PacMan` called `p`. Then, inside the `Show()` method, you ask `p` where is it located, using something like `p.getX()` and `p.getY()`.

Comment: Excellent! It moves :] However, even though i have it set as
`PacMan p = new PacMan(6,2);
 Tablero[PacMan.getY()][PacMan.getX()]=p;`
It's always starting at [0][0]

Answer (score 0):

One reason why you get `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` is the fact that in your loop you're moving `PacMan` to position `[i][j +1]`, where `j + 1` may be greater than array length.

You need to check if `j + 1 < Tablero.length` when you're 'moving' `PacMan`.

Also you can simply move the same instance of `PacMan` instead of creating a new one:

```
     ...
     if (Tablero[i][j] instanceof PacMan) {
            if (j + 1 < Tablero.length) {
                Tablero[i][j+1] = Tablero[i][j];
                Tablero[i][j] = null;
            }
       }
```

Comment: That could make PacMan disappear! :)

Comment: You can also add a return once you have found PacMan